# .htaccess RewriteRules to nginx.conf

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-routing

I would like to convert this .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Into a nginx.conf file. So far my nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  root /var/www/app;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

I am getting a 502 bad gateway error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your location for compatibility with your apache rewrites:

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
  }
```

And error 502 means that fpm-php (fastcgi) backend is down, but this is not nginx issue :)

Comment: Still does not work! But thank you very much for your help anyway!

Comment: location {} code dont fix 502 issue, you must start php-fpm service, but we are going into offtopic here )

Comment: I fixed the 502 issue, thanks to your support. But my MVC still does not work. It does not recognise the links (except index).